# Does a function $f^p$ belong to $L^ {\infty}$ if $f \in L^{\infty}$ for $1 < p < \infty$?

Tags: lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

I understand it should be so, considering the definition:

> $L^{\infty}( \Omega)= \{ f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}\, \mid   f$ is measurable and there is $C \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$ such that $|f(x)| \leq C$ a.e. on $\Omega \}$

That is, provided $f \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, we need to show that $f^p$ defined as $f^p= (f(x))^p$, belongs to  $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$:

We have $|f(x)| \leq C$ almost everywhere on $\Omega$. So, as for $1<p<\infty$ the function $x^p$ is non decreasing for $x$ positive, we have $(f(x))^p \leq C^p$ almost everywhere.

I think that is pretty trivial, but I have a little confusion as we are not dealing with plain supremum, but with the essential supremum, so can we ensure the inequality indeed holds almost everywhere?

Comment: Note that $|f(x)|\le C$ iff $|f^p(x)|=|f(x)|^p\le C^p$, i.e. the inequalities hold for the _same_ $x\in\Omega$. Then use the definition of the essential supremum.

Comment: @A.G. Okay, so it does not increase the measure of the set on which f is bounded.

Comment: $\{x\in\Omega\colon |f(x)|>a\}=\{x\in\Omega\colon |f^p(x)|>a^p\}$. Then use the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, if $\left|f(x)\right|\leqslant C$ for almost every $x$, then using increasingness of the map $t\mapsto t^p$ for non-negative $t$, we have $\left|f(x)\right|^p\leqslant C^p$ hence $\left|f\right|^p$ satisfies the definition of $L^\infty(\Omega)$.